# Pandas Drop Duplicates And Store Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, drop-duplicates

i use the pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates to search duplicates in a dataframe. This removes the duplicates from the dataframe. This also works great. However, I would like to know which data has been removed.

Is there a way to save the data in a new list before removing it?

I have unfortunately found in the documentation of pandas no information on this.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It uses `duplicated` function to filter out the information which is duplicated. By default the first occurrence is set to `True`, all others set as `False`, Using this function and filter on original data, you can know which data is kept and which is dropped out.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`groupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to keep the list of duplicates:

```
m = df.duplicated('group')

dropped = df[m].groupby(df['group'])['value'].agg(list)
print(dropped)

df = df[~m]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
# print(dropped)
group
A       [2]
B    [4, 5]
C       [7]
Name: value, dtype: object

# print(df)
  group  value
0     A      1
2     B      3
5     C      6
```

Used input:

```
  group  value
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     B      3
3     B      4
4     B      5
5     C      6
6     C      7
```